# pig failed to read data from localstorage

Tags: apache-pig, hadoop2

I ran following Commands which include load and dump command in pig: My file is on local and i am on standalone machine.

```
grunt> custs = LOAD 'custs' USING PigStorage(',') As (id:long,name:chararray,surname:chararray,age:int,prof:chararray);

grunt> dump custs;
```

I got this error:

```
HadoopVersion   PigVersion  UserId  StartedAt   FinishedAt  Features
2.7.1   0.15.0  sujit   2016-04-21 13:05:51 2016-04-21 13:05:51 UNKNOWN

Failed!

Failed Jobs:
JobId   Alias   Feature Message Outputs
N/A custs   MAP_ONLY    Message: java.lang.NullPointerException

Input(s):
Failed to read data from "file:///home/sujit/pig_data/custs"



Job DAG:
null


2016-04-21 13:05:51,277 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - Failed!
2016-04-21 13:05:51,278 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 1066: Unable to open iterator for alias custs
Details at logfile: /home/sujit/pig_data/pig_1461220631975.log
```

But File exists there, with required permission

```
sujit@sujit-pc:~/pig_data$ ls -l
total 4824
-rwxrwxrwx 1 sujit sujit  391355 Jun  9  2012 custs
```

Comment: you need to mention the full path while loading the custs file.. like /home/user/custs...

Comment: which execution mode are you using?? Make sure, it is `local` for accessing local filesystem files

Comment: i am using local, pig -x local

Comment: Is your filename custs? It doesn't have any extension?Specify the full path file:///home/sujit/pig_data/custs.txt

Answer (score 0):

I received this error because I had yet to copy my local file to the **hdfs**.

To copy files from your local to hdfs you can use the command

```
hdfs dfs -copyFromLocal yourFileNameHere.csv ~/yourFolder/yourFileNameHere.csv
```

*note you have to create a folder in hdfs prior. This is done with a command like-

```
hdfs dfs -mkdir /home/ubuntu/yourFolder
```

After copying my local file to HDFS, I no longer received the error.